# how to access or show the list of file available on ftp server in java

Tags: java, servlets, ftp

I want to show list of file which is available on ftp server i am working with some demo ftp server but it is not working it is showing some error , I have to get list of all file available on ftp server here is code

```
  public class getFTPfileList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        client.connect("ftp.javacodegeeks.com");
        client.login("username", "password");
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile ftpFile : files) {
            if (ftpFile.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE) {
                System.out.println("File: "
                        + ftpFile.getName()
                        + "size-> "
                        + FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(ftpFile
                                .getSize()));
            }

        }

        client.logout();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            client.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}

}
```

The error message showing:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp.javacodegeeks.com
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:184)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:273)
at com.journaldev.servlet.getFTPfileList.main(getFTPfileList.java:21)
```

Comment: *it is showing some error*, what error???

Comment: Where are error lines you got?

Comment: Are the credentials correct? Please provide more information about the problem

Comment: rite now i cant go with live host i have this only which i found on some website so probably  credentials are correct..

Comment: can you ping ftp.javacodegeeks.com from development machine? it seems that the host is not reachable. you can also try with the ip address

Comment: I think this is the reason client.login("username", "password");. I suppose your user is not username and your password is not password, if you copied it from internet username and password should be variables (not string literals) in the original one.

Comment: sir here is one more link that is also not working... http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/12/get-list-of-files-from-ftp-server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your FTP host is either not reachable or the *host-name is incorrect and not resolved as a host-name*.

See here : [SocketClient#connect(String hostname)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#connect%28java.lang.String%29)

> **Note :** try it using IP-address of host server and ping it to check whether it is open or not.